# How do I catch 'Uncaught typeError: Cannot read property 'isModel' of undefined' during App load?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I'm developing ST2 on Chrome which uses localstorage. From time to time, it appears that the storage schema gets corrupted. When this happens, my app fails during load with "Uncaught typeError: Cannot read property 'isModel' of undefined". The only way to get my app running is to do localstorage.clear() in the console.

I'm assuming this is an ST2 bug, since the occurrence of the corruption seems unrelated to my code, or what I do in my app.

My main question is how do I catch the exception in such a way that either the app can recover, or the user is alerted as to what is going on? Right now, the app simply fails to load. I've tried wrapping the Ext.application() in app.js, but that is executing correctly. My  launch function is not being reached.

Comment: your application is trying to access model, after it has been removed from localstorage. Provide your controller coding with your question, may be then i can help.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no code. My app only ever adds to local storage. Nowhere do I remove anything. The exception is thrown by ST's internal initialisation, not in any controller code of mine.

As I stated in the question, this error occurs at random, and seems unrelated to any particular user action.

Answer (score 0):

There must be some weird thing going on with your app. Probably you have found the reason meanwhile and recognised the failing bit is somewhere in your app. Anyway if you are experiencing anything like this then probably the best bet is to catch the error event and do your error handling there. I.e.

```
window.addEventListener("error", function(errorEvent) {

    //
    // Add your error handling here
    //
    // if returns true, the error is suppressed and not thrown
    return false;
 });
```

Comment: Many thanks for posting an answer. I abandoned ST some time ago in favour of AngularJS.